# Daniell integral and its use in probability theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Is there an axiomatization of probability theory equivalent to Kolmogorov's and one that is based on the Daniell integral instead of the Lebesgue measure? (I can imagine something along the lines of an introduction that would start out with expectation being the fundamental concept.)

Comment: That's equivalent to Lebesgue-(Stieltjes-)integral, so it would be just the same in other words.

Comment: It could help to give some more context to your question. It is a very common thing that lack of context gives very bad feedback to questions.

Comment: @Professor_Vector Of course, that is true; I was just asking if there is any known attempt to do it that way, say, for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Expectation-Springer-Texts-Statistics/dp/0387977643

Comment: @aduh thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: there is [a fourth edition](https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Expectation-Springer-Texts-Statistics/dp/0387989552/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1501102959&sr=1-1&keywords=probability+via+expectation) @aduh